# What WPF control should I use when I need to have a spreadsheet/datagrid with MASSIVE amounts of columns and rows with data?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagrid

What WPF control should I use when I need to have a spreadsheet/datagrid with MASSIVE amounts of columns and rows with data?

At most there will be over 26000 colums and rows.

Best Regards, Kjetil

Comment: I would be very interested to hear what needs 67,600,000 pieces of discrete useful information, all of which the user would be interested in? :)

Comment: 26,000 columns would scare me though.  26k rows, not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to take a step back and ask "why?"

Is a human really going to scroll through 26k columns looking for information?

Perhaps this is an opportunity to create a better UI metaphor for analyzing all that data.  I’d like to help provide a solution, but without knowing the business domain it would be a futile gesture.

Answer (score 0):

I would give DataGrid a shot for this. WPF DataGrid has built-in support for virtualization. You can also try to set the VirtualizationMode property to Recycling, to see if it gives you better performance.

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encountered similar situation with you. I resolved the issue with [UI Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338) and [Data Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344).

What is the best for me is [this](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=378), where famous Virtualization approaches, [Paul McClean](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx) and  [Vincent Van Den Berghe](http://bea.stollnitz.com/files/52/DataVirtualization.pdf), were upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a DataGrid, but you can use whatever control you want as long as it's virtualizing.

The issue I see is that if you try to bind to a standard array or other collection as your backing to store the data you'll end up with 676 million cells allocated (26000 times 26000) even if there's little to no data in there.  My suggestion for your backing store would be to create your own class based on SortedList<int, SortedList<int, object>> that only contains data for cells that are populated.  You can then create a this[row, col] operator that gets or sets cell data and that can be used to bind into your control.  Then only the cells that have data will be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a datagrid.

Use something that doesn't even attempt to work with such huge datasets.  Write something that has two scrollbars - when you scroll, it retrieves/updates the subset of data you want to view and displays it in some useful way.

Dealing with such a large amount of data will require some careful and in-depth design and consideration.  I suggest you write your own control.  If you are unsure how to tackle this very complex task, I suggest you start from first principles, come up with a plan and give it a go - then come back with the questions you will likely have in managing such a huge amount of information.

Comment: a virtualizing datagrid has 2 scrollbars and retrieves subsets of data as needed...

Comment: @John: but needs to be bound to some data source that will have to store all the data at once, no?

Comment: it needs to be bound to a datasource, but not necessarily one that contains all of the info at once.  you'd have to implement some interfaces yourself instead of using some of the easy to use built in collection things, but it can be done.